# JSON.parse is not working

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, parsing

I'm having a very strange problem. My JSON.parse does not seem to work. I tried using eval too but that didn't help either. Below is my code:

```
var responseDoc = xmlHttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML=responseDoc;
var response = JSON.parse(responseDoc);
document.getElementById("debug2").innerHTML=response.category;
```

My responseDoc looks like this

```
{"id":null,"category":"dog","price":"4321","name":"new product 123","sku":"1234","success":true}
```

But response.category is `"undefined"`. Any ideas why this is happening? I've spent hours on it but couldn't figure out. Thanks a lot!

****UPDATE****:

Removed stringify as some people suggested -> still not working.

If I tried the code below, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" from the console:

```
var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

****UPDATE 2 ****:

Found the problem. It's because my responseDoc is getting an HTML Doc. Not a JSON Object. Not sure why that happens. This is the code where I process ajax request (I'm using jsp):

```
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        result.put("success",true);
        result.put("id",request.getParameter("id"));
        result.put("name", request.getParameter("name"));
        result.put("sku",request.getParameter("sku"));
        result.put("price",request.getParameter("price"));
        result.put("category",request.getParameter("category"));

        out.print(result);
        out.flush();
```

Comment: Looks good to me! http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilpatil/m5Kdq/ any specific browser?

Comment: @NikhilPatil: The issue is specific to fetching the data via XMLHttpRequest (where the response is a string, not an object) - code that dumps the value as a literal is unlikely to be a good parallel.

Comment: @cloudfeet You're probably right about that. Cause apart from the obviously unneeded stringify, rest of the code is valid (should work) So culprit must be the data being fetched (or the way its being fetched)

Comment: Dao Lam: since you're using Chrome, you should breakpoint your code and inspect the values.  When you do so, you will see that the value of `responseDoc` is a *string*, not an object.

Comment: Dao Lam: You should also be able to see that the value of `response` is also a string, not an object - this is because of the counter-productive use of `JSON.stringify()`.  Take the stringify out, and then tell us what you see as the value of `response`.

Comment: @DaoLam please tag the server side language you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to *stringify* a string :

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseDoc);
```

Comment: Hi, that was what I had originally but didn't work so I played around with it. But not having stringify does not solve the problem... :(

Comment: try using `console.log(responseDoc)` to see if it's really the string you think it is.

Comment: Yes. The console prints out the correct value for responseDoc.

Comment: Dao Lam: does the console print out something that looks like JSON, or does it print out a fancy multicoloured thing which you can click on to do things?  If it's not multi-coloured, then it's `responseDoc` is a string, not an object.  Since `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify` cancel each other out, that means that `response` is also a string, not an object.

Comment: Actually my console says that the line console.log(responseDoc) gives something like this:


`<html>
<title>VIEW PRODUCTS</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
        {"id":null,"category":"dog","price":"123","name":"it's me","sku":"120391","success":true}
   
</body>
</html>`

Comment: there you go... you are getting HTML document as response. Not a JSON

Comment: Yes I guess that's my problem. Why is it getting an html doc as a response?

Comment: Could be anything in the webservice. My wildest guess would be you are trying to return a string in the webservice rather than using Context.Respose ...

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `stringify` something that is already a string (`xmlHttp.responseText`). The `stringify` method should be used on a javascript object to serialize it into a JSON string. So get rid of this stringification and simply parse the JSON string that you already have (using the `JSON.parse` method):

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseDoc);
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I had that originally but read somewhere that I should use stringify so I added that.

Comment: Using stringify there is still completely wrong.  You might have a *second* problem as well, but anyone who can help you is going to stop when they see that stringify.  You need to remove the stringify and *then* tell us what your problems are.